# Can every finite product of cosines be rewritten as a finite sum of cosines?

Tags: trigonometry

I used TrigReduce on products of cosines in Mathematica.

It led to me to develop the formula $\prod_{i=1}^k\cos\left(\beta_i\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}\frac{\cos\left(P_j\right)}{2^{k-1}}, k \geq1$ where $P_j$ is a permutation of the signed sums of $\beta_i$'s, i.e.
$\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3+\beta_4+\beta_6$ and $\beta_1-\beta_2+\beta_3-\beta_4+\beta_6$ are two of the 32 permutations with $k=6 $ ($\beta_1$ always has a positive coefficient).

How would I prove this? Is this formula out there in literature?

I tried proving it by using the chain rule and then reverse because integration is linear over sums, and derivatives make sine functions more "summy". Then was going to use a recursive formula to prove by induction. But that line of reasoning doesn't explain how the $\beta$'s get in the same cosinusoidal term. Also, nothing in my undergrad used this and I couldn't find anything on google. And Mathematica doesn't give the general formula when I use k instead of a fixed number. ( I also get something similar with sinusoidal products).

Comment: I'd write $\cos\beta_j=\frac12(e^{i\beta_j}+e^{-i\beta_j})$.

Comment: I could easily write your comment into an answer, but I wouldn't have been able to figure it out for awhile without your help. If you write it out I will up it.

Comment: More or less all the trigonometric formulas follow from $\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is easily shown by indution.
Suppose we have ($j_1=1$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{k-1} \prod_{i=1}^{k} \cos( \beta_i) = \sum_{j_2 \in \{1,-1\}} \cdots \sum_{j_k \in \{1,-1\}} \cos \left( \sum_{i=1}^{k} j_i \beta_i \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply this by $2 \cos( \beta_{k+1}) $ and use $2 \cos(A) \cos(B) =\cos(A+B) +\cos(A-B)$. The summands on the RHS will become
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \cos \left( \sum_{i=1}^{k} j_i \beta_i \right) \cos ( \beta_{k+1} ) = \sum_{j_{k+1} \in \{1,-1\}} \cos \left( \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} j_i \beta_i \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I think on LHS the factor should be $2^k$. Otherwise you have to consider only half of all the choices for the signs  (OK since $\cos$ is even), say by $j_1= 1$.

Comment: Thanks @orangeskid ... I had not thought about the base case carefully enough ... Well spotted!

Comment: No problem... in fact it was in the OP already...nice, clean solution, +1.