# Is there a sum-to-(sum of)-products-rule for arbitrary number of cosines?

Tags: trigonometry

It is striking that in lists of trigonometric identities like [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) there is a product-to-sum rule for a product of arbitrary number of cosines, namely $\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\theta_k\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{\{e_k = \pm 1\}}\cos\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} e_k \theta_k\right)$.

However there is no counterpart for a **sum** of arbitrary number of cosines. The $\{\theta_k\}$ in here are assumed to be arbitrary, i.e. with no special relation between them.

I conjecture that this should be a (sum of)-products rule, in the form of

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\theta_k\right)=\sum_{\{e_k = \pm 1\}}\prod_{a_{k,\{e_k\}}}\cos\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k,\{e_k\}} \theta_k\right)
$$

The notation is to say that for any permutation $\{e_k\}$ there is a product with a new set of coefficients $a_{k,\{e_k\}}$ inside the $\cos$-functions. It is desired that not for all permutations such products are present; indeed the fewer the better.

**Examples**:

For $n=2$ there is the well-known rule: $\cos(A)+\cos(B)=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$.

For $n=3$ one can write (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709702/is-there-any-expression-to-calculate-the-sum-of-at-least-3-cosines?noredirect=1&lq=1)): $\cos(A)+\cos(B)+\cos(C)=\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{A+C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-C}{2}\right)$.

The last example already illustrates the above statement that a small number of products is desired, since here one can argue that the RHS with three more complicated terms than the three terms on the LHS doesn't produce a great improvement. I  know of no more compact form  for $n=3$.

**Question:** is there a formula which transforms  a sum of arbitrary number of cosines into a convenient (sum of)-products of cosines ?

Comment: You can of course group any sum in a sum of pairs, plus an optional sum of three angles. E.g. $\cos(A)+\cos(B)+\cos(C)+\cos(D)=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)+ 2\cos\left(\frac{C+D}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C-D}{2}\right)$

Comment: @MartinR Martin, yes. This roughly halves the number of terms. The desire would be to reduce the number of terms on the RHS further, by "including" more angles in the arguments of the $\cos$-functions.